# Determine a basis for $U^\perp.$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ be the space spanned by the vectors
>   $v_1=[1,-1,0]^T$ and $v_2=[1,0,-1]^T$. Determine a basis for
>   $U^\perp.$

In the solution they say that:

> $U^{\perp}$ is equal to the nullspace of the matrix
>
> $$A^T=\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & -1\end{bmatrix},$$
>
> where its rows are $v_1^T$ and $v_2^T$. By rowreduction we obtain
>   $U^{\perp}=\text{span}(u)$ where $u=[1,1,1]^T.$

**Questions:**

1) Does this mean that $U$ is not a space but a plane since two vectors in space can only span a plane?

2) Why is it equal to the nulllspace of $A^T?$

3) Why is it not equal to the nullspace of $A$ instead?

4) What is the answer? They have not given a bssis for $U^{\perp}?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Does this mean that $U$ is not a space but a plane since two vectors in space can only span a plane?**

Any plane through the origin is a vector space. So it can be both.

**2) Why is it equal to the nulllspace of $A^T?$**

For real values matrices, it's because the dot product is defined by the transpose: $u \cdot v= u^Tv$. So since you're looking for all the vectors perpendicular to the column space of $A$ this means finding all $x$ such that $a \cdot x=a^Tx=0$ for all a in $A$. In particular it's enough to check that this works for every vector that is in a basis for $A$ (or a span of the columns). Write out 
$$
A^Tx=\begin{bmatrix}v_1^Tx\\ v_2^Tx\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}v_1\cdot x\\ v_2\cdot x\end{bmatrix}
$$
So you can see that settin $A^Tx=0$ gives a solution to all vector perpendictular to these vectors.

**3) Why is it not equal to the nullspace of $A$ instead?**

The null space of $A$ is the solutions to $Ax=0$ this is looking for solutions to $A^Tx=0$. The nullspace of $A$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ in your example the nullspace of $A^T$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ so they can't even be the same.

**4) What is the answer? They have not given a bssis for $U^{\perp}?$**

First note they have given you a basis for $U$ then they find the basis using something like the following

Row reduce

$$A^T=\left[\begin{array}{rrr}1 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & -1\end{array}\right]
\sim \left[\begin{array}{rrr}1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1\end{array}\right]
$$

Note when you solve $Ax=0$ the 3rd coordinate of $x_3$ variable is free so $x_3=t$. Then multiplying out by $x$ you get equations 
$$
\begin{align}
x_1-x_3&=0\\
x_2-x_3&=0
\end{align}
$$
So solving gives $x_1=x_2=x_3=t$ so solutions have the form $x=t\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$. So a basis for $U^\perp$ is $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, U is a plane.  Note that U is the span of two vectors.  And in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a plane.

To be in $U^\perp$, the vector needs to be perpendicular to $v_1$ and $v_2$.  That is, $v_1\cdot x= 0$ and $v_2\cdot x=0$.  Another way to write this is $v_1^T x= 0$ and $v_2^Tx=0$.  This can all be written as $A^T x = 0$.  Do you see it?

So now you need to find the null space of $A^T$ to get a vector in $U^\perp$.  $A^T x = 0$ implies $x_1-x_2=0$ and $x_1-x_3=0$.  If we let $x_1=1$ then $x_2=1$ and $x_3=1$.  Do a vector in $U^\perp$ is $(1,1,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. The span of two vectors is a plane, not a three dimensional space.
2. I don't know why they call the matrix $A^T$ instead of $A$ nor do I know why they chose this solution. $U^{\perp}$ is one dimensional and is spanned by the vector that is the cross product of $v_1$ and $v_2$.
3. As above, I don't know why they used that notation but the reason the solution is the null space of that matrix is because vectors in $U^{\perp}$ must be perpendicular to both of $v_1$ and $v_2$. That matrix encodes those two dot products and the fact that each must be zero.
4. Take the cross product of $v_1$ and $v_2$.

Comment: 1. The word “space” is overloaded. In the quoted text, it’s pretty clearly a shorthand for “vector space.”

Comment: 2. Using a cross product is a short-cut that only works in $\mathbb R^3$. The approach presented in the quoted text is more general.

Comment: @amd In point 1, the quoted text means vector space but the question asked "Does this mean that U is not a space but a plane since two vectors in space can only span a plane?". That is clearly a question about geometry. As to point 2, my third answer acknowledged why that approach works. However, the problem was in $\mathbb R^3$ so whether to use a matrix or a cross product is a matter of taste.

Comment: 1. My point is that you address the letter of the question without taking the provided context into account. The answer is incomplete. It’s most likely that (1) was prompted by the use of the word “space” with no modification to describe $U$. 2. “... nor do I know why they chose this solution.” That’s why.